# Custom Product Attribute Not Showing In Admin (Magento 2.4.0)

Tags: magento2, admin, entity-attribute-value

Just wondering why the following script seems to to add the new records to `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` yet the attribute doesn't show up in the admin when I edit a product:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Ash\GiftWrapFee\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Eav setup factory
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'giftwrapfee_applied',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Apply Giftwrap Charge',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'frontend' => '',
                'backend' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 50,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

After this I ran bin/magento setup:upgrade and then like I say, the tables update correctly in the database but for some reason, there is no attribute when I check in the catalog products in the admin area.

Thanks guys for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out for anyone else who may stumble on the same issue in the near future. The fix was to basically to update:

```
'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
```

to

```
'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(**['setup' => $setup]**);